# Read and print sequences and print merged sequence

Tags: java

I suppose to write a Java program using array and method follows: It reads a sequence of strings, each on a separate line, and stores them in an array, let call it input1, with one string per cell, in the order they were read. The sequence ends with an empty line: one with a String of length 0. Same thing with 2nd sequence.Then prints the 1st sequence and 2nd sequence. And then create an array that contains all of the elements of the above two arrays. Merging is done by alternating between the arrays: that is, the first cell of input1 is copied followed by the first cell of input2. Then the second cell of input1 is copied followed by the second cell of input2. Of course, in general, the two sequences may have different lengths, so after the shorter sequence is finished, all elements of the longer sequence are simply appended to the output array. Finally, prints the merged array with 1 string each line.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A4 {
public static void readInput(Scanner myScanner, String[] input) {
    boolean streamEnded = false;
    int index = 0;

    while (!streamEnded && myScanner.hasNext()) {

        String value = myScanner.nextLine();

        if (value.length() == 0)  {
            streamEnded = true;
            input[index] = value;
        } else {
            input[index] = value;
            index++;

        }
    } 

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 5;
    String[] input1 = new String[size];
    String[] input2 = new String[size];
    String[] store = new String[size*2];

    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    readInput(aScanner, input1);
    for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("input[" + i +"]" + input1[i]);
    }

    readInput (aScanner, input2);
    for (int i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("input[" + i +"]" + input2[i]);
    }

}
```

}

i still dont know how to merge those 2 inputs together.Can anyone show me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare three arrays for sequence 1, sequence 2 and merged-sequence.

Use a variable whichToUse to store which array to be used and assign array1 to it before the while loop, then store values into array1 on the place of System.out.print, then when first reach value.length()==0 ('=' is not designed for comparing, it's a mistake in your code.), you change the whichToUse point to array2. When the second reach value.length()==0, end the reading loop. One place to be marked, declare streamEnded as a int to count how many times we reach the value.length()==0. Only exit loop while streamEnded==2.

Now you have two arrays which contains the values from file. Next step is to merge them. Use a for loop to iterate items in merged-sequence, and use loop-counter%2 to determine which array to read when assign value to merged-sequence items. after any of the array1 and array2 reaches the end, read the other array in the rest of loop.

As looks like you are new to Java, I think write code by yourself is much better than I provide the code to you. If you've any other question, just comment here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am sorry i am kinda slow, can you explain more or give me some more hint. THanks, appreciated it

Comment: here what i got so far

Comment: You just need to iterate the third array, and determine which value the current item should be assigned to.

Comment: For the first item of third array, 1%2=0, then get first value from array1. And so on

Comment: I'm on my phone, so can't provide code. Sorry for that.